# calculate direction to move to by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There is a tank(group), I need to control (move), panzer must go in the direction where its muzzle is looking

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.code === 'KeyW') {
        model.position.z += -0.1
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyA') {
        model.rotation.y += 0.01
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyD') {
        model.rotation.y += -0.01
    } else if (event.code === 'KeyS') {
        model.position.z += 0.1
    }
})
```

the tank always moves in z, when I change its rotation it still moves in the direction of z, but it should move diagonally - where the muzzle is looking

Comment: your code doesn't take into account the muzzle

Comment: how i can do this?

Comment: maybe you have something similar so i can figure it out?

Comment: You can find a tutorial. The game of asteroids seems very much like you project. You can borrow some ideas from https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MeGyjE for example